# Custom module's output is not wrapped in the site theme

Tags: 7, theming

I've put together my first Drupal 7 custom module. I've implemented hook_menu() to get it to path correctly, but I cannot seem to get the output wrapped in the page tpl.

I can visit domain.com/mycustommodule to see the output, but it's just the photos and links that the custom module built, not the site wrapper. How do I get this output into the node area of the page?

Here's my hook_menu if that helps.

```
function mymodule_menu() {

$items = array(); 
$items['mymodule/view'] = array(
'title' => 'Mymodule',
'page callback' => 'mymodule_display',
'access callback' => 'user_access',
'access arguments' => array('Access administration menu'),
'weight' => 1,
'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
return $items;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What would help is the code for the `mymodule_display()` function. However, it sounds like you are printing the output in the function instead of returning it.

Blank page:

```
/**
 * Creates a blank page with only the module output.
 */
function mymodule_display() {
  print 'Module content';
}
```

Themed page:

```
/**
 * Output the content in the main content area of active theme.
 */
function mymodule_display() {
  return 'Module content';
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. I'm printing out the location of images on the local file system, as the location changes by the date. There's not much to that function, other than a for loop going back fourteen days and returning the images for those days. Thanks for your help, enzipher!

Answer (score 0):

You should go to domain.com/mymodule/view to see the output of your `mymodule_display` function.

The complete code will be

```
function mymodule_menu() {
 $items = array(); 
 $items['mymodule/view'] = array(
 'title' => 'Mymodule',
 'page callback' => 'mymodule_display',
 'access callback' => 'user_access',
 'access arguments' => array('access content'),
 'weight' => 1,
 'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
 );
 return $items;
}


function mymodule_display() {
 return '<h2>Heres is your module's output</h2>';
}
```

Make sure you clear cache after writing this code.