# How to make a non-Drupal page and where to place it?

Tags: users, 7

I need to create a page (it's receipt) which is not drupal-page. How it should work:

1. User clicks the link in "User Menu" or in "User Profile"
2. This link is made from link to custom page itself and user's $POST parameters (name and address fields, for example).
3. This page consists of HTML tags, CCS styles and PHP $POST-parameters and finally creates a PDF (to print).

I know how to make modules and use Hooks (I made custom registration), and I can use Drupal database (normal and fields entries). But how I should realize this task? And where I should place my custom page's file?

Comment: Why you need this to be a non-Drupal page? You can do with Drupal, even if you are calling an external library for the PDF.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) At the moment it's not clear what you're asking (what does "user's $POST parameters" mean? Why are you refusing to do this properly and use hook_menu()? And so on). We also obviously can't help you with writing general PHP code, as it's nothing to do with Drupal, so this leaves what you're asking at "where do I put a PHP file?", to which the answer is "wherever you want it". Please edit your question to make it clear what about _Drupal_ you need to know, and remove the parts about generating PDFs with PHP, etc. Once the question is clear please flag for re-opening

Comment: @tunic I consider it as non-Drupal page, cause it doesnt have any drupal wrapping. It's external page with HTMl tags and PHP-script.

Comment: @Clive I want a clear non-Drupal HTML-page with PHP-scripts. I tried to do it with hook_menu(), but I always received the same result - Drupal wrapping around my page. I used as "return NULL" as "exit()" neither works. And if I use hook_menu() how should I implement my template without Drupal wrapping?
Yeah, I think I can just make some simple links in menus, but I wanted to do it in a "Drupal way", cause I like proper ways.

Comment: Did you try just printing your result in the page callback? If you don't return from said callback the normal theme wrappers won't be executed

Comment: @clive After I asked this question I look at function again and just print variable with html-markup. Now I have some issues with Clear-URLs and $_GET parameters, but it's another question.
Btw, answer to my question is here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/73192/custom-modules-output-is-not-wrapped-in-the-site-theme

Comment: @Clive Should I answer to my own question?) I have good example of how to print result in the page callback (I mean reutrn NULL;).

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a custom module and implement hook_menu() for you custom page.
Here you get details about hook_menu "https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7".

To get this link on user menu tab use type as
 'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK
And write your page code by calling a function
'page callback' => 'user_details',

create user_details function and write code for custom page.

Comment: I've used hook_menu() earlier, but it creates page with drupal framework. I need clear page (receipt or bill as I said) to generate PDF from it.

Comment: Don't return the content, just print it and put an exit  call at the end of the callback function, as Clive said in another comment. Then your content will not be wrapped by Drupal.